# Using Lucene Highlighter along with MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: parsing, lucene, lucene-highlighter

Im using Lucene Highlighter to highlight the matches that I have found in a Lucene Index. Now, my problem is that If I have to search multiple fields of a document, and I need to display the matching text, then how can I get in which field the hit has occurred?

The code which I am using for the highlighter is basically the second function  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997009/problems-using-lucene-highlighter)

If I do not know in which field the hit has occurred in, then what field do I pass to the function defined above to get the matching fragments?

Comment: Same problem here ... Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Can you generate highlighting on each field separately? It will involve several calls, but since they are on different fields, there should be no loss of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the fields into a single text field and run your highlighter on it.